# How to take data from an excel file and create JS variables or objects with it?

Tags: javascript, excel

I have an excel sheet with about 900 lines of data points. Basically it's a date "mm/dd/yy" and a number value that corresponds with that date. Without creating 900 different variables by hand, is there a way to import this data or read the excel sheet? Eventually Users will be inputting 2 dates and a function will fine the difference between the values assigned to those dates.

I have a function that can import the sheet and display the data as a bootstrap table on the web but I need to be able to interact with these data points.

Comment: Use an array, in that case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.